# Use __dirname in Import statements

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a DB models directory something like this: `src/sequelize/models`.

I've to import the same file into multiple files. So my `import` statements in different files look like this:

**src/index.js**

```
import db from './sequelize/models';
```

**src/facebook/index.js**

```
import db from '../sequelize/models';
```

**src/api/resolvers/index.js**

```
import db from '../../sequelize/models';
```

Is there any way to use `__dirname` in `import` statements? So that in every file I can use something like:

```
import db from __dirname + '/sequelize/models';
```

However the above import statement gives error!

Comment: What's wrong with relative paths? (And no, this is not possible, by design).

Comment: Just for the record, could you show the error you got?

Comment: @GijoVarghese The working `'../../sequelize/models'` seems to be a relative path?